# Robospice for non-web service usage

Tags: android, sftp, robospice

Is that possible to use Robospice for SFTP data transfer ?
It is using HTTP for web service at the moment but I need the same thing for the SFTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

RoboSpice is protocole agnostic and doesn't depend at all on HTTP or any other network protocole. You can even find a sample using it completely offline (for instance to compute a fractal).

The only thing is that you will have to write your sftp requests using a third party lib to tackle the sftp protocole.